# How to Group value stored in Redis using Hash type?

Tags: redis

I have used Hash data type to store data as shown in given code snippet:

**Field 1**

```
c7b05551-97fa-4492-a949-0e8f3660129f
```

**Value 1**

```
{"Currency":"USD","guid":"c7b05551-97fa-4492-a949-0e8f3660129f","price":"86.143","quantity":"48071"}
```

**Field 2**

```
c9b05851-98fa-4592-a946-0e8f5660129f
```

**Value 2**

```
{"Currency":"USD","guid":"c9b05851-98fa-4592-a946-0e8f5660129f","price":"86.143","quantity":"42"}
```

I want to group by price, and want sum of quantity.
In mongoose it is possible to do with Aggregation Group and Sum.
Is it possible to do with Redis?

Comment: It is **impossible** to do that in redis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is **impassable**. The best way to do this by using [sorted set](https://redis.io/commands/zadd). Make price as scores and store the quantity values in set.By using [ZUNIONSTORE](https://redis.io/commands/zunionstore) you can sum the quantities with same scores(price).